# Log Internal Error in C# without a try-catch block

Tags: c#, runtime-error, try-catch

I'm programming in WPF C# (in MS Visual Studio) and I'm looking for some technology that automatically logs (to some file) a line number in the source code (where the error occurred) if the program (Release *.exe file) crashes due to an internal error. Can it be done without a try-catch block in the source code? Thank you for your advice.

Comment: If you do not apply a try/catch mechanism, how would you identify that an error occured?

Comment: Not usually a good idea to depend on it for logging in .NET, but if your app crashes because it currently does not handle an exception, it will usually be logged to the Windows Event log (Application), with a stack trace with line numbers (if available).